# Query returning null on a column with info

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got a few different tables, one is `hotel` and contains information in regards to a chain of hotels, and another is `room` which contains information about the rooms within the hotels.

I'm trying to query the database for a list of the hotel names along with the room numbers ordered in a certain way. Ordering them is easy, but I've had trouble trying to hack up some code to make this work.

What I've got is:

```
SELECT
    hotelName,
    roomNo
FROM
    hotel
RIGHT JOIN
    room
ON
    hotel.hotelName = room.roomNo
```

This works, it joins the tables and presents all the room numbers but all the hotel names are returned as null. I've been working on this for a few days now, its part of my study, but I just can't work out how to get it to work. The tables aren't connected via and keys but as far as I can tell that shouldn't matter, and it didn't matter with the normal and LEFT JOIN's.

Cheers for any help on this one guys :)

This is the database presented in the designer on phpMyAdmin and the result I'm getting with the current code. The only difference I need is that the hotel name shows the actual hotel names stored in the database.

[image]

Comment: You have rooms which don't belong to hotels?

Comment: Why do you do right join? I can't see why you need it here. (And most people prefer left join, so much easier to understand "main table left join optional data".)

Comment: what is the foreign key on the `room` table that relates a room to a hotel? Semantically, `hotelName` and `roomNo` should not be related.

Comment: `hotel.hotelName=room.roomNo` seems to be a very strange join... I'd try `hotel.hotelid =room.hotelid` or similar, and a regular inner join.

Comment: I can't use right join for this one because its related to an assessment piece.

Comment: There isn't a foreign key related with the two tables, but its a database created entirely from a data set given by my college. It should theoretically work this way, as so many other people have done this assessment already

Comment: Show us some sample table data (for both tables), and the result you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are linking the hotel and the room via hotel-name and room-number, i think it should be:

```
SELECT
    hotelName,
    roomNo

FROM
    hotel

INNER JOIN
    room

ON
    hotel.HotelNo = room.HotelNo
```

The `right join` makes only sense if you can have hotel-rooms which don't belong to hotels, so i've used an `INNER JOIN`.

Of yourse the name of a hotel is not a good primary key. You should define a `HotelID` instead. A hotel-name and a room-number seem to be two completely different things. **Update:** **The new image of your db shows that it's `HotelNo`**

I guess you have forgotten to add a foreign-key-column to hotel in your room table. `HotelName` is a bad candidate because multiple hotels with the same name are possible. You need a unique identifier. Create a primary-key column in `hotel`(f.e. `HotelID`) and a FK column to hotel in `room`(hotel a room belongs to). You could name this column also `HotelID`.

Comment: This returns an "Unknown column 'room.hotelName' in 'on clause'"

Comment: Naturally I'd much rather have a proper ID for hotel to make things neater but this is just layed out the exact way the assessment asked. From my understanding RIGHT JOIN is hardly ever used in any real scenario.

Comment: @Slappy: it should just show you what's wrong, i don't know your db schema. You were linking both tables via `roomNo` and `hotelName`, does that make sense? A hotel-name and a room-number seem to be two completely different things. I guess you have forgotten to add a foreign-key-column to hotel in your room table. `HotelName` is a bad candidate because multiple hotels with the same name are possible. You need a unique identifier. Create a primary-key column in `hotel`(f.e. `HotelID`) and a FK column to hotel in `room`(hotel a room belongs to). You could name this column also `HotelID`.

Comment: I linked a picture with the lay out I was given to work with, but I think you're right. I might just pull the trigger and make that adjustment to the database and let whoever marks it that I needed to.

Answer (score 0):

You should use inner join and proper conditio for join

```
SELECT
    hotelName,
    roomNo
FROM hotel
INNER JOIN room ON hotel.YourHotelID=room.YourHotelID;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tables aren't connected via an unique foreign key (e.g hotelID) in the child table, there is no way you can tell which rooms belongs to a specific hotel

Comment: Foreign keys are handy, but never required.

Comment: You have to safe an unique reference from the parent table in the child table, ofc you can do that plain without an actual reference but that would be very bad practise.